# big O complexity of recursive tree functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm not sure about the O() complexity of these functions. My answers are in the boxes. Someone told me they are all O(n) but I don't understand why that is. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Big-Oh complexity and "best-case" makes no sense.

Comment: At the **very** least, don't take a photo when text will suffice. It would have taken moments to type out the questions.

Answer (score 3):

All four are O(n) (ignoring that the two best case questions should use Ω(n)) since you must examine every node.

Consider `height`: you have to recursively check each subtree, terminating only once you reach the bottom of a tree. That means you're going to reach every leaf node eventually. You can't terminate early.

The same goes for `balanced`; you can't verify that a tree is balanced without first verifying that each subtree is balanced, which in this implementation means calling `height` for each subtree.

---

Now for the wording of the exam. Big O notation is used for worst cases because a worst case is (by definition) "bigger" than all other cases. An upper bound for the worst case is necessarily an upper bound for all cases. Similarly, a best case is by definition "smaller" than all other cases. An upper bound on the best case is mostly useless, because you can't say anything about the remaining cases.

When talking about best cases, you use Ω (big omega) notation, which provides a *lower* bound. Saying the best case is Ω(n) tells you that no matter how good the best base (and thus every case) is, it's no smaller than n.

For `height` and `balanced, you can actually show that the best case is Ω(n) *and* the worst case is O(n). In that case, you can combine them and say that each is Θ(n); the upper and lower bounds match.

Comment: You bring up the fact that `height()` is called for each node down the recursive path, on `balanced()`... That would make it greater than `O(n)`, since it traverses back down the tree for each node, right?

Comment: Possibly; I haven't looked at the actual implementation closely (too busy on my giant tangent on upper and lower bounds). A *good* implementation would be O(n) :)

Comment: From the way it's implemented, if the left subtree is unbalanced then it won't even check the right subtree and will return false. So if the left subtree is very small (let's say 2 nodes and is unbalanced), then wouldn't it be O(1)? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: A *good* implementation would store the height as part of the Node class and increment appropriately as nodes are added to the tree. Then both of these methods could be done in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

`height()`
Best case: both left and right trees are null. Therefore `O(1)` for a single max comparison, though technically, `n = 1`, so you can say `O(n)`.

Worst case: must completely traverse both left and right trees when neither is null. `O(n)`

---

Same for `balanced()`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Best case is still O(n), as n=1 in that case.